# How can an out-proc COM server detect client failure?

Tags: windows, com, interop

Say we have an out-proc COM server and a client. The client calls a method in the server and unexpectedly terminates. Is there a way for the server to detect this and interrupt the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without a keep-alive.  There is a built-in keep-alive mechanism if you are using DCOM.  The DCOM server will pingback to the COM client periodically, and if 3 pings go unanswered, the server declares the client "gone" and the server-side object can go away.

If it is not DCOM then...?

Comment: It's actually an ATL in-proc server put into a COM+ application. Can it use any mechanism?